# ag-grid filter api: filterComponent.selectValue() not working when grid has no matching rows

Tags: ag-grid

Using the filter api, I'm trying to show all rows in a grid with a status of "Deleted" (or "Active" conversely).  If there are no rows containing that value in the grid, the grid is not filtering - it stays filtered as it already was, as if no action was taken.

Below is the logic being used upon a button click (to filter to the "Deleted" records)

```
gridProps.api.getFilterInstance('Status').selectNothing();
gridProps.api.getFilterInstance('Status').selectValue('Deleted');
```

Are there any known issues around this, or insight as to what would cause this?  When the grid contains 1 or more rows with a "Deleted" status, the filtering works without any issue.

Comment: do you let ag grid know that filter was changed externally by calling this.gridApi.onFilterChanged()

Comment: @PratikBhat yes, good question